# nginx ingress client certificate authentication

Tags: nginx-ingress

I am trying to enable client certificate authentication in my ingress, but it does not works.

I followed https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/client-certs/ and the example of https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/client-certs/ingress.yaml

Thus the annotation I used was `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"`

However, nginx does not ask client for a client certificate.

Besides, I am not able to find such info. in page https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/#backend-services-upstreams

Is client certificate auth not supported by this version of nginx ingress controller ?
If yes, what is the correct annotation to use ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/2822), NGINX ingress controller does not support client certificate authentication